# PHP array_column() with potentially null columns

Tags: php

Does anybody know a way of getting a result of "5" from this this without using a for/foreach?

```
$array = [
    ['number1' => 1], 
    ['number1' => 1],
    ['number1' => 1], 
    ['number2' => 2], 
]

echo array_sum( array_column( $array, 'number1' ?? 'number2' ) );
```

I understand why my example does not work (the string `'number1'` is never null).

If not, how much less performant would a for or a foreach be than using array_column?

Comment: array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $array))

Comment: `foreach()` would perform better than any of the array functions to be honest. Behind-the-scenes these PHP array functions perform a loop anyways so you're just adding overhead by using the functions; we're talking minuscule though.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree, I wouldn't bother with this for performance reasons. I think the main reason to use functions like that rather than loops is code style preferences rather than a performance gain. Some folks prefer a loop for readability, others like something more concise.

Comment: @Don'tPanic True but for the fun of it I did benchmark 1,000,000 iterations of OP's sample array and your solution takes 2.5x more time than a vanilla `foreach(){}`. We're talking `0.1 s` vs `0.25 s` though...

Comment: `array_sum(array_column(array_map('array_values', $array), 0)))` I hope everyone here likes exotic solutions :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Well that's not fair, a million is too many. The `array_` functions get tired faster because they have to look cool while doing the same thing. ;-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Good point. I definitely failed to consider the coolness factor and its substantial benefit 

Comment: ... more exotic: `array_reduce($array, function($a, $b) { return $a + reset($b); }))`

Comment: Looks like I committed the cardinal sin of oversimplifying my example. All the answers are dependent on the value being the first or only item in the array. What I was looking for was a way to add together values extracted from an array, but default to value at a 2nd key if the 1st specified key doesn't exist; was hoping to use null coalesce operator in there somehow. Having said all that, it's great to know that `foreach` is not less performant than `array_column`, which I always thought it was. As a bonus, it'd be great if someone could explain how array_column works under the hood.

Comment: @jessica Can you provide a non-oversimplified array sample and the expected behavior? If I understand you correctly then my answer should still be valid with minimal modification but I won't know for sure unless you provide a better sample array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness sake this is the most performant way to achieve your desired result.

```
$total = 0;
foreach( $array as $sub_array )
{
    foreach( $sub_array as $value )
    {
        $total+= $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to always take the first item from the inner array regardless of its key, you can map `reset` to imitate `array_column`.

```
echo array_sum(array_map('reset', $array));
```

`array_sum`, as others have suggested, will also work, but if any of the inner arrays have more values that wouldn't give you the result you want.